# How to increase max_user_connections through my.cnf on cloudcontrol

Tags: mysql, cloudcontrol

do i have any chance to reach the my.cnf to increase the

max_user_connections

on cloudcontrol? Untill now, the max_user_connections are limited to 2

Comment: Contact their support department.

Comment: They are using Stackoverflow for community support.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you use `mysqls.free`. On mysqls, `max_user_connections` depends on the plan of [mysqls](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/add-ons/mysqls). So just pick a bigger plan to increase the limit.

For mysqld I'm not sure, but you get a decicated mysql-server.

Comment: Thank you! I found the pricing plans, in which the 2 connections are mentioned under the free plan: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/add-ons/mysqls